# How to verify that all products are sorted by Name (A TO Z) using C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, sorting, selenium-webdriver, automation

**In Selenium WebDriver, if I select drop down value by 'name' then how do I verify that all products are sorted by name?**

```
IWebElement productSort = TestSetup.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span/select[@data-test='product_sort_container']"));
                productSort.Click();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    
                IWebElement name = TestSetup.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div/span/select/option[@value='az']"));
                name.Click();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are fun. The way I have accomplished this is to create a list of the before view and then the sorted view into a list. Then take the before view and sort it via linq and then run a compare.

add libraries:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

             
            List<String> item = new List<string>();
            // grab the data that you want to sort
            IReadOnlyList<IWebElement> cells = TestSetup.driver.FindElements("your xpath for all items in the list");
            // loop through and add into into the ArrayList
            foreach (IWebElement cell in cells)
            {
            item.Add(cell.Text.Trim());
            }
            List<string> listDefault = item.Select(e => e).ToList();
            List<string> listSorted = listDefault.OrderBy(x => x).ToList(); //sort list asc to compare
            Assert.IsTrue(listDefault.SequenceEqual(listSorted));
```

Comment: It looks like you are using MS Test. Why not use [CollectionAssert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert)?